# Backbone view won't load JST

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, jst

I have an app that utilizes Backbone.js. Everything was working fine, but recently I added RequireJS to my project, and that of course made everything break, so I'm in the processes of defining my dependencies and making everything work again.

The error I'm getting is `Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined.`

I have the following CoffeeScript view file. Note the JST line:

```
define ["app"], (App) ->
  Snip.Views.Appointments ||= {}

  class Snip.Views.Appointments.IndexView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST["backbone/templates/appointments/index"]

    initialize: () ->
      @options.appointments.bind('reset', @addAll)

    addAll: () =>
      @options.appointments.each(@addOne)

    addOne: (appointment) =>
      view = new Snip.Views.Appointments.AppointmentView({model : appointment})
      @$("ul").append(view.render().el)
```

My "app" dependency itself has Backbone and Underscore as dependencies, so I don't think the problem is that Backbone is not present:

```
define ["underscore", "backbone"], (_, Backbone) ->
  window.Snip =
    Models: {}
    Collections: {}
    Routers: {}
    Views: {}
```

When I load the page, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined`.

What do I need to do to get my script to know about JST?

**Edit: here are my paths and stuff**

```
require
  paths:
    jquery: "jquery-1.7.2.min"
    underscore: "lodash.min"
    appointment: "backbone/models/appointment"
    appointmentIndexView: "backbone/views/appointments/index_view"
    appointmentsRouter: "backbone/routers/appointments_router"
    relational: "backbone-relational"
  shim:
    "underscore":
      exports: "_"
    "backbone":
      deps: ["underscore", "jquery"]
      exports: "Backbone"
    "relational":
      deps: ["backbone"]

requirejs ["appointmentsRouter"], (AppointmentsRouter) ->
  window.router = new Snip.Routers.AppointmentsRouter({appointments: []})
  Backbone.history.start()
```

Comment: show your `require.config` -function where you define the paths

Comment: New development: `JST` is evidently supposed to be defined as an array, with each element being a template. (I learned this by going back in time in my repo to when stuff used to work.)

Comment: care to add this as an answer jason?

Answer (score 1):

there is no variable called `JST` available when the module in question is loaded.

You need to add the path to your JST -library to the `paths`-attribute in `require.config`.

Then most likely you'll need to add it to `shim` also and make it export `JST`.

In require.js your alarm bells should start ringing when you use some external resource inside a module that has not been

A. Imported in the `define` -section of that module

B. Imported via `require` inside that module

C. Mentioned in your `require.config` -function

#### UPDATE

You need to make a new module (like templates.js), that returns a variable (for example `JST`).

```
define([
  ...
], function( ... ) {
  
  var JST = {};

  JST['template/name'] = "<div class='my-template'><%= my-content %></div>";

  ...

  return JST;
}
```

Then in the module you want to use those templates in:

```
define([
  ...
  'path/to/your/JST/module',
  ...
], function(..., JST, ...) {

// Et voilà, now you can use the templates like they should be used

});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. What I find confusing is that this JST thing worked fine before, but now it doesn't, but there's not like a "jst.js" file or anything like that. When I grep for JST, I get nothing. So I have no idea what it is I need to include.

Comment: Expressed more clearly: I would like to add the path to the JST library in my list of paths, but I don't know what my JST library would be. Previously, I didn't have to explicitly include any JST library, and no file on my system seems to be a JST library. (And if there's one online, it's not easy to find.)

Comment: where did you find this JST stuff?

Comment: It stands for JavaScript Templates and I didn't seek it out on my own, Backbone just uses it.

Comment: FYI, Backbone doesn't just use it. JST is just an abbreviation for the object you use to store templates in. Now, I assume you have a require.js module where you define all your templates?

Comment: No, I don't. Maybe that's part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. I got an error in my Backbone View:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined.

Below what I've done to make it work:

1. In my config/requirejs.yml I sat:

   ```
   modules:
       - name: "products/product_price_tmpl"
   ```
2. My view definition:

   ```
   define ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'products/product_price_tmpl'] , ($, _, Backbone) ->

   Backbone.View.extend

       template: JST['products/product_price_tmpl']

       tagName: 'li'

       render: ->
           @$el.html(@template(@model.attributes))
           @
   ```
3. All my templates are in the assets/templates directory. If requirejs has a problem to find your template in this directory, you can move templates directory into assets/javascripts folder or add this line to config/application.rb file:

   ```
   config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/templates"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Backbone Boilerplate which compiles the templates into one file called templates.js.  the JST is defined in templates.js. configure the paths with templates.js resolved the issue.

Comment: Would you mind showing me your templates.js so I can see an example? (I couldn't easily find such a thing on the Backbone Boilerplate GitHub.)

Comment: After install backbone boilerplate, run "bbb debug" on cmd line, the file templates.js will be generated under dist/debug/. here is what it looks like in templates.js: 
this['JST'] = this['JST'] || {};
this['JST']['app/templates/example.html'] = function(data) { return function (obj,_) {
var __p=[],print=function(){__p.push.apply(__p,arguments);};with(obj||{}){__p.push('<this will be the content of the html> ...}(data, _)};

Answer (score 0):

Whilst [Jason Swett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199712/jason-swett) was using AMD/require.js, as the question title is not specific I thought I'd answer on behalf of CommonJS/Browserify users as I ended up here after googling for the same issue.

After moving my Backbone app to Browserify is was getting a "JST in undefined error". [wawka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1534205/wawka)'s answer above helped me to get things sorted.

Before I had:

```
JST["path/to/template"]({...});
```

Now I have:

```
var template = require("path/to/template");
...
template({...})
```

Hope this is of help to others.

Answer (score 0):

Specify correct loading order

**require.config**

```
require.config({
    paths: {

        // specify templates
        templates: 'compiled-templates'
    }
})

// firstly load templates
require(['templates'], function() {

    // then load you app
    require(['core/Core']);
});
```